# Creating Dynamic Url used in QR Code which will be used in all platforms (Website, Android App, IOS App)

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, dynamic-url

I have a query that, I have to develop the QR Code which will be used dynamically as per the situation. I have already developed QR Scanner within the app and which works perfectly fine Explain with an example hope it will clear my requirements more

QR Code use cases

1. The user scans the QR Code from the installed app it will show the particular screen details which we want to show.
2. Users scan the QR Code from the default device's Camera or Scanner and it will detect that the app is installed or not.
    -> If an app installed then it will open the screen detail from the application
    -> If app not installed then open the website with the particular detail

Please let me know if this is possible or not

Comment: What kind of info you are storing in your QRcode? You can put the URL itself in the QRcode.

Comment: Hey @Dilpreet, I have doubt on the 2nd point, in my understanding, you can only do this if the scanner you are talking about is your application and any other third party scanner app or default camera will never offer this kind of functionality. So just to confirm, is the scanner is also your app?

Comment: Also, ` If app installed then it will open the screen detail from the application -> If app not installed then open the website with the particular detail` on this point.
Looks like you can achieve this functionality with a universal link that is registered with your application. So if the user scans your QR code, if will try to resolve the universal link and (if user opens the link) the app is installed, it can launch your application otherwise the universal will reedirect user to the website.

Comment: @Swayangjit, Let's say i will add the tiny url in the QR Code and it will shows the webpage for the same, but how will i handle within my app scanner for the same ?

Comment: @AnujSharma, Yes i have also scanner in my app too. Just want to manage the same QR Code from default camera and from the app's scanner

Comment: @AnujSharma.   

Universal links services like - One Link. Already used that and it works when we have a static information (Like Website Domain, App Store Link, Play Store link). 

But i am considering for the Dynamic Urls like i have multiple Business Listing and i need to create QR Code for each trying to achieve same scenario

Comment: @DilpreetSingh so you will have to parse the URL to fulfill your app  requirement

Comment: have you got the solution? to get a dynamic link from QR code inside the app scanner and get the data?